# Merge pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I got two pandas dataframes with a multi-level index (the date is the first dimension, hour of the day the second).

I would like to add one column from the dataframe `first` to the dataframe `second`. If I simply try:

```
second["new_col"] = first["new_col"]
```

I only get `NaN` values for each row in `second["new_col"]`, despite the two dataframes having exactly the same index.

I also tried to merge the frames like so:

```
second = pd.merge(second, first.loc[:,"new_col"], how = "inner")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

I got a solution myself: seems like the datatypes of the indices weren't the same. I typecasted the the index columns of each frame to `str` and `int`, which solved the problem.

How can I check for the dtypes of the index levels in advance, to avoid such mistakes?

Comment: Can you add samples of your dataframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `df.index.levels`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""Date;Time;ID
8/14/2015;3:00;aaa123
8/7/2015;4:00;aaa123
7/15/2015;2:00;aaa123
8/22/2015;7:00;aaa123
8/3/2015;1:00;bbb222
8/8/2015;5:00;bbb222
8/10/2015;7:00;bbb222"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[0],sep=";")

df1 = df1.sort_values(["Date", "Time"])
df1= df1.set_index(["Date", "Time"])

print df1
                     ID
Date       Time        
2015-07-15 2:00  aaa123
2015-08-03 1:00  bbb222
2015-08-07 4:00  aaa123
2015-08-08 5:00  bbb222
2015-08-10 7:00  bbb222
2015-08-14 3:00  aaa123
2015-08-22 7:00  aaa123
```

```
print df1.index.levels[0]
DatetimeIndex(['2015-07-15', '2015-08-03', '2015-08-07', '2015-08-08',
               '2015-08-10', '2015-08-14', '2015-08-22'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'Date', freq=None)

print df1.index.levels[1]
Index([u'1:00', u'2:00', u'3:00', u'4:00', u'5:00', u'7:00'], dtype='object', name=u'Time')

print df1.index.levels[0].dtype
datetime64[ns]
print df1.index.levels[1].dtype
object
```